# regular expression to find nth letter from end of string

Tags: java, regex

To find regular expression whether nth character in a string from the end is a character from the set `{a,e,i,o,u}`.

Eg:

```
n=10;
String=algorithm
```

It is `true`. Since `a` is the tenth letter from the end is in the set.

```
n=5;
abcdefg;
```

It is `false`. Since `c` is the fifth letter from the end.

How to identify an regular expression for the above pattern?

Comment: algorithm doesn't have 10 letters.  nothing is the 10th character from the end.

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression?

Comment: @Marvin https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/regular-expresso/challenges/vowels-in-the-back

Comment: @PavanManjunath. Thank you. So it's basically one of those "I'm too lazy to think myself" questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the end anchor:

```
[aeiou].{<n-1>}$
```

`<n-1>` needs to be replaced with the proper value, of course. In Java, that would be:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
//...
String patternString = "[aeiou].{" + String.valueOf(n-1) + "}$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
//...
```

Comment: Don't need `String.valueOf`, just need the parenthesis: `"[aeiou].{" + (n-1) + "}$"`